# Javascript - Using looped var with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spservices

Attempting to generate a list of hyperlinked items using the SPServices library. How would I call or return the looped variable inside a a href? The way it currently is coded only renders the string "list[i]['Name']".

```
This code works not using a href:
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=document.getElementById("output").innerHTML+list[i]['Name']+"</br>";

This only provides the string:
$SP().lists(function(list) {
  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++)document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=document.getElementById("output").innerHTML+"<a href=list[i]['Url']>list[i]['Name']</a>"+"<br>";
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cant use variables in string like this, you have to concat them like:
`var string = "this is the value of variable x: " + x + "!";`

Comment: note the `+` in my previous comment